# Cant install MySQL Becouse no Root Permissions?

Tags: mysql, linux

Hello I want to Install MySQL to my Vserver, I created a New user, but I cant Install MySQL becouse I have no root permissions for the user

What can I do now?

Linux - Debian 9

```
apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php

apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php-mysql

apt-get install phpmyadmin

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

 echo Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: You are also installing apache and php, not just mysql. This will be hard to do without root or a sudoer user, though not impossible. Read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges to get an idea how hard it will be.

Comment: I just created it In root wit Xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just substitute with sudo:

```
sudo su
apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php-mysql
apt-get install phpmyadmin
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
echo Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```